# Scaffolded Web API Create Action parameter is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

Inside a WebAPI MVC project, I have an EF object called `ServiceKey`. It's just a few columns.

Had VS scaffold/generate the MVC 5 Controller with Views (using EF). It creates all the methods I need. Create, edit, delete, etc. To be clear, this is "right out of the box" controller and view. Using the pregenerated Create function results in a null parameter. Here's the code it generated:

```
    // POST: ServiceKeys/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,serviceKey,consumer,created,modified,deleted,deletedDate")] ServiceKey serviceKey)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ServiceKeys.Add(serviceKey); //throws exception here
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(serviceKey);
    }
```

`serviceKey` is null and so EF throws an error saying that the entity can't be null:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity
```

To be sure, here's my routes:

Web API Route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Why is this failing right out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

*sigh*

Because apparently if you have a column with the same name as the table, EF and MVC get confused on which one is which.

In this particular example, the table was named the same as the column and since this was a test and the serviceKey guid was to be autogenerated when I extended the db context, it wasn't being filled in in the form.

Hence, it thought that the model.serviceKey column was really the ServiceKey *object* and since it was null, it got cornfuzzled.

*slow clap for Microsoft*

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `ServiceKey` instance name from `serviceKey` to `seviceKeyObj` or something else and the problem will be solved. The instance name should be different from its class name.